# Getting error on JUnit test

Tags: java, junit

So the assignment my professor has given does not allow me to edit anything on the JUnit test because our class that we have written has to match with her Javadoc. So everything is working fine except I am getting an error and 3 failures. No matter what I try I can't seem to fix these. How can I fix an error and make all tests pass without changing the JUnit Test, I just can't spot the error. Basically in general how do you get rid of errors in JUnits and failures while not changing the JUnit.
Here is my company class

```
/**
* @author Amin Oskoui
* This is the company class aka the data manager which contains the majority of the methods and holds the arraylist.
*/
import javax.swing.*;

import java.util.*;
public class Company {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;//ensuring that the class corresponds with a serialized object


Employee a;

private String companyName;//name of company


final int maxCompanies = 2, maxEmployees = 7, maxSales = 1, maxDesign = 2, maxManufacturing = 4;

private static int numberOfCompanies;//the number of companies
private int numEmployees;//the number of employees
public int numDesign;//the number of employees in design
private int numManufacturing;// the number of employees in manufacturing
private int numSales;//the number of employees in sales

private ArrayList<Employee> employeeList;

/**
 * 
 * @param cn parameter for cn
 */
public Company(String cn){
    numEmployees = 0;
    numSales = 0;
    numDesign = 0;
    numManufacturing = 0;
    companyName = cn;
    numberOfCompanies++;
    employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
}
/**
 * 
 * @param employeeCount parameter for employeeCount
 * @param numDesign parameter for numDesign
 * @param numSales parameter for numSales
 * @param numManufacturing parameter for numManufacturing
 * @param companyName parameter for companyName
 */
public Company(int employeeCount, int numDesign, int numSales, int numManufacturing, int numOfCompanies) {
    this.numEmployees = employeeCount;
    this.numDesign = numDesign;
    this.numSales = numSales;
    this.numManufacturing = numManufacturing;
    this.companyName = companyName;
    numberOfCompanies++;
    employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
}
/**
 * 
 * @param fName parameter for fName
 * @param lName parameter for lName
 * @param parameter for p
 * @return
 */
public String addEmployee(String fName, String lName, String p) {
       /**
        * @return returns a string with an error message
        */
    if (numEmployees >= maxEmployees) {
        return "There is already 7 employees\nEmployee not added";
    }


    switch (p) {//switch statement for each case
        case "Sales":
            //if there's less than 1 salesman, add them to the list
            if (numSales < maxSales) {
                Employee employee = new Employee(fName, lName, p);
                employeeList.add(employee);
                numSales++;
                numEmployees++;
                return "Salesperson added successfully!";
            }
            else {
                /**
                 * @return returns a string with an error message
                 */
                return "There is already a sales person\nEmployee not added";

                }


        case "Design":
            if (numDesign < maxDesign) {
                Employee employee = new Employee(fName, lName, p);
                employeeList.add(employee);
                numDesign++;
                numEmployees++;
                return "Designer added successfully!";
            }
            else {
                /**
                 * @return returns a string with an error message
                 */
                return "There are already two design persons\nEmployee not added";            
                }


        case "Manufacturing":
            if (numManufacturing < maxManufacturing){
                Employee employee = new Employee(fName, lName, p);
                employeeList.add(employee);
                numManufacturing++;
                numEmployees++;
                return "Manufacturer added successfully!";
            }
            else {
                /**
                 * @return returns a string with an error message
                 */
                return "There are already four manufacturing persons\nEmployee not added";      
                }
    }
    /**
     * @return return statement just to make sure the program operates properly.
     */
    return "This should never appear";
}
public static int getNumCompanies(){//return the number of companies 
    return numberOfCompanies;
}
public int getNumEmployees(){//get the number of employees
    return numEmployees;
}
public String printCompany(){//print the company with all of the positions
    String companyPrint = companyName + "\n";

    return companyName;
}

public String employeeListString() {
    String s;
    s = companyName + "\n";
    for (Employee e : employeeList) {
        s += e + "\n";
    }
    return s;
}
/**
* @param s passes the String s
*/
public void setCompanyName(String s) { 
    companyName = s;
}
public void clearEmployees() {
    numEmployees = numDesign = numManufacturing = numSales = 0;
    employeeList.clear();
}

@Override
public String toString() {//converts everything to a string
    return "Company [position="  + ", companyName=" + companyName
            + ", employees=" + employeeList + ", numEmployees=" + numEmployees
            + ", numDesign=" + numDesign + ", numManufacturing="
            + numManufacturing + ", numSales=" + numSales + "]";
}


}
```

And here is the JUnit test for it.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;


/**
* This is a JUnit test program to test the Company.
* The following classes must be defined and implemented:
* Position - enumeration
* Employee - data element
* Company - data manager
* @author Professor Myers changed by Prof. Justh
*
*/
public class CompanyTester {

/**  A Company object reference used for testing */
Company company, studentCompany;

@Before
/** This method is run before each individual test
 *   Creates an object of Company and adds three
 *   Employees to the Company
 */
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    company = new Company("New Source");
    company.addEmployee("John", "Smith","Manufacturing");
    company.addEmployee("Bob", "Brown", "Manufacturing");
    company.addEmployee("Harold", "Jones", "Sales");
    company.addEmployee("Betty","Boop", "Design");

    //STUDENT: Create your own instance of company (studentCompany) and add employees.
    //You will use this studentCompany instance in the STUDENT test methods

}

@After
/** This method is run after each individual test
 *   It sets the Company reference to null so the garbage
 *   collector can reclaim the memory used for the
 *   Company object
 * @throws Exception
 */
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    company = null;
}

@Test
/**
 * Test to 
 * 1.  check if the number of employees is originally 4
 * 2.  Add another employee, and check if number of employees is 5
 * 
 */
public void testGetNumEmployees() {
    assertEquals(4,company.getNumEmployees());
    company.addEmployee("George", "Jones", "Design");
    assertEquals(5, company.getNumEmployees());
    company.addEmployee("Susie", "Smith", "Manufacturing");
    assertEquals(6, company.getNumEmployees());
    company.addEmployee("Susie", "Smiley", "Manufacturing");
    assertEquals(7, company.getNumEmployees());
}

@Test
/**
 * Use the studentCompany instance
 * Test to 
 * 1.  check the original number of employees
 * 2.  Add another employee, and check if number of employees has increased by 1
 * 
 */
public void testGetNumEmployeesSTUDENT() {
    assertEquals(4,company.getNumEmployees());
    company.addEmployee("John", "Mayhew", "Design");
    assertEquals(5, company.getNumEmployees());
    company.addEmployee("Sally", "Sams", "Manufacturing");
    assertEquals(6, company.getNumEmployees());
    company.addEmployee("Max", "Schmidt", "Manufacturing");
    assertEquals(7, company.getNumEmployees()); }

@Test
/**
 * Test to
 * 1.  add 3 new Employees as a manufacturing person
 *     check if recognizes there are already 4 manufacturing persons
 * 2.  add a new employee as a sales person
 *     check if recognizes there is already a a sales person
 * 3.  add 2 new employee as a design person
 *     check if recognizes there is already 2 design persons
 */
public void testAddEmployee() {
    String result;
    //add another designer - No problem, should return null
    result = company.addEmployee("Bobby", "Match", "Design");
    assertEquals(null, result);
    //add another designer - already 2 designers - return error message
    result = company.addEmployee("Albert","Pine", "Design");
    assertEquals("There are already two design persons\nEmployee not added", result);
    //add another sales person - already 1 sales person - return error message
    result = company.addEmployee("Susie", "Smith", "Sales");
    assertEquals("There is already a sales person\nEmployee not added", result);
    //add another manufacturer - No problem, should return null
    result = company.addEmployee("Benedict", "Cumberbatch", "Manufacturing");
    assertEquals(null, result);
    //add another manufacturer - No problem, should return null
    result = company.addEmployee("Martin", "Freeman", "Manufacturing");
    assertEquals(null, result);
    //add another manufacturer - already 4 manufacturers - return error message
    result = company.addEmployee("Andrew", "Scott", "Manufacturing");
    assertEquals("There are already four manufacturing persons\nEmployee not added", result);

}

@Test
/**
 * Test to
 * 1.  add a new Employees as a manufacturing person
 *     check if recognizes there are already 4 manufacturing persons
 * 2.  add a new employees as a sales person
 *     check if recognizes there is already a a sales person
 * 3.  add new employees as a design person
 *     check if recognizes there are already 2 design persons
 */
public void testAddEmployeeSTUDENT() {
    fail("Test not yet implemented");
}

@Test
/**
 * Test to:
 * 1.  Check if the company name is on the first line
 * 2.  Check if John is on the second line
 * 3.  Check if Bob is on the third line
 * 4.  Check if Harold is on the fourth line
 * 5.  Check if Betty is on the fifth line
 */
public void testPrintCompany() {
    String result = company.printCompany();
    Scanner company = new Scanner(result);
    assertEquals("New Source",company.nextLine()); 
    //extract three Employees
    assertEquals("John", company.next());
    company.nextLine();  //Smith     Position design (rest of line)
    assertEquals("Bob", company.next());
    company.nextLine();  //Brown     Position manufacturing (rest of line)
    assertEquals("Harold",company.next()); //Harold
    company.nextLine();  //Jones     Position Sales (rest of line);
    assertEquals("Betty",company.next());
}

@Test
/**
 * Test to:
 * 1.  Check if the company name is on the first line
 * 2.  Check if other employees are in order as entered
 */
public void testPrintCompanySTUDENT() {
    fail("Test not yet implemented");
}

@Test
public void testMoreThan1company()
{
    //created company and studentCompany instances
    assertEquals(2, Company.getNumCompanies());
    //create another company instance
    Company company2 = new Company("New Company");
    assertEquals(3, Company.getNumCompanies());

}
}
```

Here is the employee class

```
 /**
 * @author This is the employee class which is also the data element in charge of holding    the information for the employee entered by the user.
 */
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

 public class Employee {
private String fName;
private String lName;
private String p;

public Employee(String fName, String lName, String p) {
this.fName = fName;
this.lName = lName;
this.p = p;

}
public String getFName(){
    return fName;
}
public String getLName(){
    return lName;
}
public String getP(){
    return p;
}
public String toString(){
    return fName + " " + lName + "  " + "Position: " + p;
}





}
```

Comment: And what errors do you get? Which tests fail? That would be helpful to know.

Comment: Also, post the `Employee` class.

Answer (score 1):

Look through the tests. Look at what they expect your program to produce. Then look at what your program is producing. For example, this is from one of the tests:

```
String result;
//add another designer - No problem, should return null
result = company.addEmployee("Bobby", "Match", "Design");
assertEquals(null, result);
```

That means the test expects `addEmployee()` to return `null` when it is successful. Is that what your `addEmployee()` method does?

Now do that for all the tests and you'll have found all your errors.

Also, look at the output from jUnit. When an `assert` fails it gives you a pretty good idea why. It will say something like, `expected xxxxx to be yyyyy but it was zzzzz instead`.

Comment: Where does it say the "expected xxxxx to be yyyyy but it was zzzzz instead" I can't seem to find that in my code.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply here is the employee class.

Comment: And I know it's not the exact thing you said but where does it give an error message?

Comment: It won't say that in the code, it will say that when you run the tests.